# MSMQ cannot read from encrypted queue in C#

Tags: c#, encryption, msmq

I'm trying to implement encryption in a C# application which connects to an MSMQ queue, but I'm struggling to find any suitable documentation which applies to the particular configuration I am using.

The implementation makes use of the asynchronous `BeginPeek`, and the `PeekCompleted` event triggers the `Receive`.
The queue connection uses the format `FormatName:Direct=OS:ServerName\private$\QueueName`, and with encryption off, the implementation works perfectly fine.

With encryption on the queue set to body, I am unable to write to the queue at all, and although I have wrapped the message sending in a `MessageQueueTransaction` surrounded by a `try...catch` block, I do not get any error message (even though it clearly isn't working).

```
     private void Queue_PeekCompleted(object sender, PeekCompletedEventArgs e) {
        String messageId = e.Message.Id;
        Message m = null;

        using (MessageQueueTransaction transaction = new MessageQueueTransaction()) {
            try {
                transaction.Begin();
                m = _qc.Queue.Receive( transaction);
                transaction.Commit();
            } catch (MessageQueueException ex) {
                if (ex.MessageQueueErrorCode == MessageQueueErrorCode.TransactionUsage) {
                    throw new IncompatibleQueueException("The queue is not transactional", ex);
                }
                transaction.Abort();
                throw new QueueReadException("Unable to read from the queue. The read transaction has been aborted, and the message has not been taken.", ex);
            }
        }
     }
```

My aim is to have a library which can directly connect to a queue such that the messages sent across it are encrypted while transmitted, stored encrypted in the queue, and recieved still encrypted.

Although I could implement encryption on the message contents, I would prefer to make use of the encryption available in MSMQ if it can be implemented cleanly.
As I understand it, this requires the use of a key pair, but I cannot find any concise explanation of how the keys are distributed or used, or even if this assumption is correct.

If anybody can provide an explanation of message sending is handled when the queue is set to `body` level encryption, it would be particularly helpful (even a basic explanation would give me something to go on), or if somebody could advise how to get a stacktrace or error message from the code snippet included above, it would at least allow me to debug it further.

I have tried for the past 2 days to find a suitable example or description of how to enable encryption on MSMQ in C#, but all the examples I have found are based around WCF or Azure, and centre around a much more complex approach than I am trying to implement.

I would prefer to avoid WCF if at all possible, but will consider any alternative approach if it can potentially provide a suitable solution.

Many thanks